# PHP json_encode - JSON_FORCE_OBJECT mixed object and array output

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP data structure I want to JSON encode. It can contain a number of empty arrays, some of which need to be encoded as arrays and some of which need to be encoded as objects.

For instance, lets say I have this data structure:

```
$foo = array(
  "bar1" => array(), // Should be encoded as an object
  "bar2" => array() // Should be encoded as an array
);
```

I would like to encode this into:

```
{
  "bar1": {},
  "bar2": []
}
```

But if I use `json_encode($foo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` I will get objects as:

```
{
  "bar1": {},
  "bar2": {}
}
```

And if I use `json_encode($foo)` I will get arrays as:

```
{
  "bar1": [],
  "bar2": []
}
```

Is there any way to encode the data (or define the arrays) so I get mixed arrays and objects?

Comment: This is not possible using the built-in `json_encode` function

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Create `bar1` as a `new stdClass()` object.  That will be the only way for `json_encode()` to distinguish it. It can be done by calling `new stdClass()`, or casting it with `(object)array()`

```
$foo = array(
  "bar1" => new stdClass(), // Should be encoded as an object
  "bar2" => array() // Should be encoded as an array
);

echo json_encode($foo);
// {"bar1":{}, "bar2":[]}
```

OR by typecasting:

```
$foo = array(
  "bar1" => (object)array(), // Should be encoded as an object
  "bar2" => array() // Should be encoded as an array
);

echo json_encode($foo);
// {"bar1":{}, "bar2":[]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Same answer, for `PHP5.4+`.

```
$foo = [
  "bar1" => (object)["",""],
  "bar2" => ["",""]
];

echo json_encode($foo);
// {"bar1":{}, "bar2":[]}
```

---

Another simple examples, with something important to notice:

```
$icons = (object)["rain"=>[""], "sun"=>[""], "lightrain"=>[""]];
echo $icons->sun;
// 

$icons = (object)["rain"=>"", "sun"=>"", "lightrain"=>""];
echo $icons->sun;
//
```

Answer (score -6):

There answer is no.  There is no way for the function to guess your intent as to which array should be array and which should be objects.  You should simply cast the arrays you want as object before json_encoding them

Comment: @DarkoRomanov By casting he means `"bar1" => (object)array()`. The `(object)` casts (transform as in a smith's furnace) the array into a standard object.