# How to make contents of php nested array json objects within an outer array using json_encode

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I have an array:

```
$myAssocArray = array(
           ['fred','tyson',23],
           ['collins', 'white', 54],
           ['mary', 'frost', 46]
        );
```

When I `json_encode` the array:

```
$jsonString = json_encode($myAssocArray);
echo $jsonString;
```

I get:

```
[['fred','tyson',23],['collins', 'white', 54],['mary', 'frost', 46]]
```

But I would like the following result:

```
[{0:'fred',1:'tyson',2: 23},{0:'collins', 1:'white', 2: 54},{0:'mary', 1:'frost',2: 46}]
```

Comment: You can pass `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to the second argument of `json_encode` but that will not result in the exact value that you want.

Comment: Please don't use Markdown arbitrarily. Blockquotes (`>`) are for, well, quotes. They're not for emphasis. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hi, I think that this means nothing in JSON `"[{'fred','tyson',23},{'collins', 'white', 54},{'mary', 'frost', 46}]"`.

Comment: (a) Your PHP isn't an associative array, it's just an array of arrays. (b) The output you're showing is also an array of arrays, so it makes sense. (c) Your expected output isn't valid JSON. It's impossible to get that output from `json_encode()`.

Comment: It seems to have worked after I cast the sub arrays to objects

Comment: You are right ankabout, should be something like , '[{"0":"collins","1":"white"}]'. I was just trying to describe the problem not necessarily get the syntax right

Answer (score 0):

Found a solutiion, I had to cast the nested array to objects

```
(object) $myDynamicNestedArray;
```

[PHP json_encode - JSON_FORCE_OBJECT mixed object and array output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670575/php-json-encode-json-force-object-mixed-object-and-array-output?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Chris I understand the output i typed in the quesstion is not valid json (I was just free styling on the keyboard not checking syntax), but the problem is still valid if you change it to a valid json string

Comment: I just edited the final json output in the question. With regards to the answer. $dataArray->push((object)$data->all()); $dataArray->toJson(); ended up giving me the output I was expecting

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `array` to an `object` `(object)$array`, something like:

```
function _json_encode($arr){
   return json_encode((object)$arr); 
}

$jsonString = _json_encode($myAssocArray);
print_r($jsonString);
```