# How to serialize associative array of objects to JSON object?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I would like to serialize object using the Symfony (5.3) Serializer to the following json:

```json
{
    "a": [
        {"id" 8 },
        {"id" 5 }
    ],
    "b": {
        "13": {
            "id": 13
        },
        "5": {
            "id": 5
        },
        "11": {
            "id": 11
        }
    }
}
```

Serialization code looks like this

```php
$object = new MyObject()
$object->addA(new A(8))->addA(new A(5));
$object->addB(new B(13))->addB(new B(5))->addB(new B(11));

$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);

$serializer = new Serializer([
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new DateTimeNormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter, null,  new ReflectionExtractor(), null, null, []),
], $[new JsonEncoder()]);

$serializer->serialize($object, 'json');
```

*Code and example are simplified*

There is no problem with `a` field, but I want `b` (and only `b`) should be serialized to a JSON object like in the example above. How can I do this? Do I need a custom normalizer?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov I'm aware of json_encode. But I have to use Serializer for serialization/deserialization

Comment: Since the serializer (encoder) only differentiates between iterable or object to determine the resulting json, there is no way to have a mix `A` as an array and `B` as an object using the serializer alone. You can force objects by using `$serializer->serialize($object, 'json', ['json_encode_options' => \JSON_FORCE_OBJECT]);` Otherwise, you will need to convert the iterable to an object, eg: `$b = new stdClass();` or `$b = (object) [];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP json\_encode - JSON\_FORCE\_OBJECT mixed object and array output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670575/php-json-encode-json-force-object-mixed-object-and-array-output)

Comment: Since the serializer `JsonEncoder` internally uses `json_encode`, the same approaches will apply.

Comment: @WillB. `['json_encode_options' => \JSON_FORCE_OBJECT]` will convert every array to object. `{a: {{...},{...}}, b: {{...},{...}}}` but I need `b` only

Comment: @Constantine please reread my comment, I stated you can "force objects" by specifying that option, but not mixed array and objects when using only the serializer. You would have to refactor your `MyObject` class, like so: https://3v4l.org/O7D9E#v7.4.25.

Comment: @WillB. MyObject is a class, A and B classes too. And I need `b: {something: {...}, anything: {...}}` instead of `b: {{...},{...}}`

Comment: I understand your requirements. As in the duplicate question, the original issue is caused by the `MyClass::$b` property being an `array` of objects. Not an `object` of indexed objects. You need to change it as I demonstrated in the link I provided. eg: `public function addB(B $b) {  $this->b->{$b->id} = $b; }`

Comment: @WillB. I finally got your point and found my own mistake. `public function addB(B $b) {  $this->b[$b->id] = $b; } public function addA(A $a) {  $this->a[] = $a; }` does exactly what I need. **Thank you!** I would accept your answer if you add it.